# Use ls to show only certain number of items

Tags: unix

I'm trying to get a simple `myhead` command in C to show the top 10 lines of the first five .HTML files in a directory. I was advised to use ls to carry this out in conjunction with my `myhead` command. My main issue is with getting ls to only show 5 .html files and not list them all.

I was thinking something like this

```
ls *.html -n 5 > myhead
```

However, that doesn't exist. Any ideas? We are only meant to use `ls` and `myhead`.

Comment: Try `more command `

Comment: So `myhead` is a script of your own that outputs first ten lines of a file? Or first 10 lines of each file passed in as argument?

Comment: What is the `myhead` command? What does it take as arguments or stdin?

Comment: I see that 40 minutes ago you edited your question so it is very different, essentially a new question.

Comment: It's the same question, just reworded it so it's easier to understand. The title explains it very well, which hasn't been edited - "Use ls to show only certain number of items"

Comment: @FShiwani yes my answer #1 should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you've written a C program `myhead` that prints out ten lines of a file passed in.

You definitely don't want to do this

```
ls *.html -n 5 > myhead
```

This would overwrite or create a new file `myhead` in the current directory.

The key thing needed to achieve this are command line *pipes*. This allows the stdout of one command to be the stdin of the next command. Also you'll need [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) which is having the stdout output of one command, or piped commands, be used as text for another command. Historically this has been done with backticks `ls`, or in bash you can use `$(ls)` as an example to get a `ls` listing and use it as text for another command.

Given you're okay with the standard `ls` file list order you can do this to get the first 5 .html files:

```
ls *.html | head -n 5
```

I don't know what `myhead` is or how it works as it's not explained in the question. You say it shows the first ten lines of a file passed into it. There could be a few it does that.
I'll give a solution for each possibility (assuming you're using bash):

1. take one file at a time, passed in as an argument

`for f in $(ls *.html | head -n 5) ; do myhead $f ; done`

2. take multiple files at a time, passed in as multiple arguments

`myhead $(ls *.html | head -n 5)`

3. take the contents of a file passed in through *stdin*

`for f in $(ls *.html | head -n 5) ; do cat $f | myhead ; done`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I think I have it sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are [pipes](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html)

You can use them like this:

```
# all the output (STDOUT) of ls is passed as the input (STDIN) of myhead
ls *.html | myhead -5
```

`myhead` reads the input on STDIN, and outputs N lines of it on STDOUT.

Comment: Wouldn't that just print the top 5 lines of all the html files and not just 5 .html files?

Answer (score 0):

With the standard Unix `head` command, you can do this:

```
head -n 10 $(ls | head -n 5)
```

First, you should run this command exactly as shown in your shell to verify it works.  Next, try it with your `myhead` command instead of `head`.